# How to do a makefile function that generate rules an return to build objects

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the current code
It allow me to easily generate object files of binary files

```
define ASSET_RULE
$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(1))): $(1)
    $(LD) -r -b binary $(1) -o $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(1)))
endef


SRC=avatar.jpg  \
    avatar2.png

OBJ=$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRC)))

NAME=assets.a

all: $(NAME)

$(foreach file,$(SRC), $(eval $(call ASSET_RULE,$(file))))

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(AR) rcs $(NAME) $(OBJ)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: clean fclean all re
```

I would like to do a function that take assets as parameter, generate rules for them and return me the .o file to compile as dependencies.
By the end I expect to have something like.

```
ASSETS=avatar.jpg   \
    avatar2.png

OBJ=$(call BINARY_ASSETS,$(ASSETS))

NAME=assets.a

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(AR) rcs $(NAME) $(OBJ)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: clean fclean all re
```

I tried to combine my foreach loop of eval with the final object names however I'm getting `*** prerequisites cannot be defined in recipes.` when I'm doing that.
Is it possible to do this kind of things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to update `OBJS` inside `ASSET_RULE`, because the macro will only be able to return the makefile code for `$(eval)`. I've left out all the parts from your makefile that aren't relevant for the problem at hand:

```makefile
# $(1): source file name
define ASSET_RULE
_obj_name := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(1)))
$$(_obj_name): $(1)
        $(LD) -r -b binary $$< -o $$@

OBJS      += $$(_obj_name)
_obj_name :=

endef

# $(1): list of source files
BINARY_ASSETS = $(eval \
        $(foreach _a,$(1), \
                $(call ASSET_RULE,$(_a)) \
        ) \
)

ASSETS := \
        avatar.jpg   \
        avatar2.png
OBJS   :=

$(call BINARY_ASSETS,$(ASSETS))

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJS)
```

Test run where I replaced the `eval` with `info` to show the generated code:

```
$ make
 _obj_name := avatar.o
$(_obj_name): avatar.jpg
        ld -r -b binary $< -o $@

OBJS      += $(_obj_name)
_obj_name :=
   _obj_name := avatar2.o
$(_obj_name): avatar2.png
        ld -r -b binary $< -o $@

OBJS      += $(_obj_name)
_obj_name :=

make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

---

If you want to update different variables with `BINARY_ASSETS` then you'll need a second parameter to pass in the variable name:

```makefile
# $(1): source file name
# $(2): variable name to add object file name to
define ASSET_RULE
_obj_name := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(1)))
$$(_obj_name): $(1)
        $(LD) -r -b binary $$< -o $$@

$(2)      += $$(_obj_name)
_obj_name :=

endef

# $(1): list of source files
# $(2): variable name to add object file names to
BINARY_ASSETS = $(eval \
        $(foreach _a,$(1), \
                $(call ASSET_RULE,$(_a),$(2)) \
        ) \
)

$(call BINARY_ASSETS,$(ASSETS),OBJS)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OBJ=$(call BINARY_ASSETS,$(ASSETS))
```

This is wrong, as `OBJ`'s value, i.e. `$(call ...)`, gets expanded (i.e. invoked) later, inside of other recipes and prerequisites, which is the cause of make's complain. You may use only simple assignment here:

```
OBJ:=$(call BINARY_ASSETS,$(ASSETS))
```

Consult make's manual on [two flavors of variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html) (if you find, like me, this text poorly understandable, just try to imagine that '=' operator in make assigns to a variable a literal string untouched).

Also, I strongly suggest to make use of automatic variables whenever possible, e.g.:

```
$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $?
```